# Install php-mssql on XAMPP/CentOS 7

Tags: php, sql-server, apache, centos, xampp

I want to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server with my Xampp Server (CentOS 7).

I ran the following commands:

```
yum install -y epel-release
yum install php-mssql
service xampp restart
```

When I call `mssql_connect('192.168.0.1, 1433', 'user', '***');` in my PHP file it throws the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/index.php on line 39
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I thought Xampp uses Apache?

Comment: Ok I use Xampp on CentOS

Comment: @NullPoiиteя XAMPP is for Windows and Linux [See download page](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html)

Comment: sorry my bad ... didnt know it since its been ages i  used it, thanks for info

Comment: Hi @John Brunner were you able to install php-mssql to centos 7?